# WS Client and server in one java project

Tags: java, maven-2, cxf, webservice-client, java-ws

How can I have a Webservice client and server in one project (which defines a server, that will be exchanging some data among cluster of that servers instances)? Specifically, I am using Apache CXF + maven for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should not client and server in the same project. These are both completely different entities